# Leaflet: Mixing continuous and discrete colors

Tags: r, colors, leaflet, r-leaflet

I have created a map using `leaflet` in R. It is a map of the United States with polygons being zip code level. I want to color the zip codes using a continuous color palette based on some value. I have followed the example [here](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/colors.html) and have successfully mapped each zip code with a continuous color using the `colorNumeric` function like this:

```
# Create a continuous palette function
library(leaflet)
library(rgdal)
library(dplyr)

# From https://raw.githubusercontent.com/datasets/geo-boundaries-world-110m/master/countries.geojson
countries <- readOGR("json/countries.geojson", "OGRGeoJSON")
map <- leaflet(countries)

pal <- colorNumeric(palette = colorRamp(c('#4575B4', '#D73027', '#FFFFBF'), interpolate="linear"), 
                    domain = countries$gdp_md_est)

map %>%
addPolygons(stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 1,
            color = ~pal(gdp_md_est))
```

What makes this complicated is that now I want to separately color zip codes (basically replacing the previous color) using a discrete color palette. As a simple example, I want to use the `colorNumeric` function above to color each zip code based on average weight. Then I would use another zip code level field in my data to make all zip codes' polygons black if I wanted to exclude it for some reason, otherwise it would leave the colors as they already are.

I have found it difficult to use `leaflet` and `colorNumeric` to achieve both continuous and discrete coloring of my map. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add example data.

Comment: @jaySf Sorry about that, I was using different data (unfortunately I cannot share) but thought the example copied from Leaflet's website would work. I found a link and edited my question.

Comment: If you wanna have a discrete variable, you need to use `colorBin()` or `colorFactor()`, I think.

Comment: @jazzurro I agree that those would work to get a discrete variable, but my overall question is how can I combine a continuous color palette for one variable, and then overwrite that for some polygons with a discrete color palette?

Comment: @Hutch3232 I see. It seems that you need to have two layers. Let me try to give you a hand. Give me a bit of time.

Comment: @Hutch3232 My code below allows you to choose either layer. You can choose both layers as well. So the key is how you arrange your data. For example, if you want to fill in 10 regions with a continuous variable, you need to subset your data. Likewise, you want to fill in the other 10 regions with the discrete variable,  you need to subset data. Hence, you will need two data frames. Using each of them, you want to set up colors. My guess is that you cannot interactively subset data unless you create a shiny app. I hope this will help you.

Comment: @jazzurro Thank you for the code below and the comments! I like the layering idea but in my particular case I would need the method you described here where both are displaying at the same time, and ideally there would be only one legend for both continuous and discrete, though that may be very difficult. If you already have the code to display both at once, could you please provide it to make this a nice and complete answer? Thanks!

Comment: @Hutch3232 I do not have such a code in my hand. That's why I gave you the comment above. As I said, you need to create two data sets. You can subset data with `subset()` or `filter()`. I am sure you can handle this. Give it a go by yourself. I think this is a good chance for you to learn the task. If you leave your code in your question, I am happy to have a look. But that will be some time this weekend. Now I need to go to bed.

Comment: @Hutch3232 See the update. I cannot do anything with the legend thing. You gotta have two legends no matter what until there is an update in the package or writing in JS.  Last thing, I highly encourage you to write your code as much as you can rather than throwing a sample code from the leaflet introduction page. This is the only way you can push your boundary and become a better coder. SO is a place where people give you hands, but not a place where people write codes for your work or study. Please remember that.

Comment: @jazzurro First of all, thank you so much for taking the time to provide a great answer, much appreciated! I also wanted to say that I had every intention of trying it myself first, but did not have a chance yet; so I was waiting to respond until I had had a chance. I definitely agree with your comments about trying it for myself, not waiting for an answer. Thanks again!

Comment: @Hutch3232 Pleasure to help. There are many people who do not show any attempts. When you try something and doing something wrong, that is OK. Thats when you can provide your code and ask questions. Then, people are likely to help you more. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the sample above is not enough to have a demonstration, I decided to use one of the dummy data that I used for other leaflet related questions. I hope you do not mind that. Given what you said, you need to create two layers in your map. One for a continuous variable, and the other for a discrete variable. This means that you need to create two sets of colors. As you used, you want to use `colorNumeric()` for the continuous variable. You want to use `colorFactor()` for the discrete variable. In my sample code, I create a new discrete variable called `group`. Once you finish creating the color palettes, you want to draw a map. You need to use `addPolygons()` twice. Make sure that you use `group`. This is going to appear in the layer control button on the right upper corner. As far as I know, we cannot display one legend only at the moment. I came across this issue before and concluded that we have no choice at the moment. I hope this demonstration is enough for you to make a progress in your task.

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)

# Get UK polygon data
UK <- getData("GADM", country = "GB", level = 2)


### Create dummy data
set.seed(111)
mydf <- data.frame(place = unique(UK$NAME_2),
                   value = sample.int(n = 1000, size = n_distinct(UK$NAME_2), replace = TRUE))

### Create a new dummy column for a discrete variable.
mydf <- mutate(mydf, group = cut(value, breaks = c(0, 200, 400, 600, 800, 1000),
                                 labels = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"),
                                 include.lowest = TRUE))


### Create colors for the continuous variable (i.e., value) and the discrete variable.
conpal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Blues", domain = mydf$value, na.color = "black")
dispal <- colorFactor("Spectral", domain = mydf$group, na.color = "black")


leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
setView(lat = 55, lng = -3, zoom = 6) %>%
addPolygons(data = UK, group = "continuous",
            stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
            fillColor = ~conpal(mydf$value),
            popup = paste("Region: ", UK$NAME_2, "<br>",
                          "Value: ", mydf$value, "<br>")) %>%
addPolygons(data = UK, group = "discrete",
            stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
            fillColor = ~dispal(mydf$group),
            popup = paste("Region: ", UK$NAME_2, "<br>",
                          "Value: ", mydf$group, "<br>")) %>%
addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("continuous", "discrete")) %>%
addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = conpal, values = mydf$value,
          title = "UK value",
          opacity = 0.3) %>%
addLegend(position = "bottomleft", pal = dispal, values = mydf$group,
          title = "UK group",
          opacity = 0.3)
```

If you choose the continuous-variable layer, you will see the following map.

[image]

If you choose the discrete-variable layer, you will see the following map.

[image]

**Update**

If you want to show both a continuous group and a continuous group together, you need to subset your data beforehand so that there is no overlapping in polygons. Using `UK` and `mydf` above, you can try something like this.

```
### Subset data and create two groups. This is something you gotta do
### in your own way given I have no idea of your own data.

con.group <- mydf[1:96, ]
dis.group <- mydf[97:192, ]


### Create colors for the continuous variable (i.e., value) and the discrete variable.
conpal <- colorNumeric(palette = "Blues", domain = c(min(mydf$value), max(mydf$value)), na.color = "black")
dispal <- colorFactor(palette = "Reds", "Spectral", levels = unique(mydf$group), na.color = "black")


### Subset the polygon data as well

con.poly <- subset(UK, NAME_2 %in% con.group$place)
dis.poly <- subset(UK, NAME_2 %in% dis.group$place)

leaflet() %>% 
addProviderTiles("OpenStreetMap.Mapnik") %>%
setView(lat = 55, lng = -3, zoom = 6) %>%
addPolygons(data = con.poly, group = "continuous",
            stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
            fillColor = ~conpal(con.group$value),
            popup = paste("Region: ", UK$NAME_2, "<br>",
                          "Value: ", con.group$value, "<br>")) %>%
addPolygons(data = dis.poly, group = "discrete",
            stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, fillOpacity = 0.3,
            fillColor = ~dispal(dis.group$group),
            popup = paste("Region: ", UK$NAME_2, "<br>",
                          "Group: ", dis.group$group, "<br>")) %>%
addLayersControl(overlayGroups = c("continuous", "discrete")) %>%
addLegend(position = "bottomright", pal = conpal, values = con.group$value,
          title = "UK value",
          opacity = 0.3) %>%
addLegend(position = "bottomleft", pal = dispal, values = dis.group$group,
          title = "UK group",
          opacity = 0.3)
```

[image]